# app:showAsAction is always showing "never" attribute

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, menuitem, android-menu

I'm just a beginner so I was trying to make an Android app specifically to learn about `menu.xml` and `ActionBar`. So I'm trying to add `MenuItems`, here's my `menu.xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:PizzaApp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_order_pizza"
          android:icon="@drawable/order_pizza"
          android:title="@string/order_pizza"
          android:orderInCategory="1"
          PizzaApp:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:orderInCategory="2"
          PizzaApp:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

Since I wanted my app to use `Material design`, I didn't actually `extend` the `AppCompatActivity`, but I used the `support.v7.app` *dependency*, just to make the app compatible. Now since `support.v7.app` library doesn't contain the `showAsAction` function, I used my `AppName` in the menu.xml instead of `android`. But the problem is that beside `action_setting` item, `action_order_pizza` is also showing up in the **overflow** instead of the **ActionBar**. Please help! And here is the `MainActivity` code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

> Note: If I'm using `android` instead of `PizzaApp`, Android Studio shows an error though still when you run the app, it works fine!

Comment: Your statement 'Since I wanted my app to use Material design, I didn't actually extend the AppCompatActivity' makes no sense. `AppCompatActivity` specifically **does** give you material design on all API levels.

Comment: @ianhanniballake - Then what does this error means `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.platform.pizzashop, PID: 2475
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.platform.pizzashop/com.platform.pizzashop.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

Comment: "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity"

Comment: @ianhanniballake - Yes, and by my statement, I meant that I wanna use `Theme.Material` not `Theme.AppCompat`. Moreover, I don't have much knowledge right now, so my complete code comes from **Head First Android Development**

Comment: `Theme.AppCompat` [extends `Theme.Material`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39088184/1676363) where available. There's no reason to directly use `Theme.Material` if you want to use any part of AppCompat.

Comment: @ianhanniballake - Okay, well it worked! The book's content may have become out-dated cause it's using `AppName` and without extending `AppCompatActivity`. thanks! Please write this as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use any part of AppCompat such as `app:showAsAction`, you should extend `AppCompatActivity` and use `Theme.AppCompat`. `Theme.AppCompat` [extends `Theme.Material`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39088184/1676363) and will allow you to use material design on all API 9+ devices.