# Tabs, Material Design and Support Library

Tags: android

**Goal:**

- Implement tabs.

**Conditions:**

- Use **only** API21+ (Lolipop+) components.
- Use Material Design.

---

Noticed that at current state Android has:

- [TabHost](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html), [TabWidget](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html) (going to be deprecated).
- [ActioBar.addTab](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#addTab(android.app.ActionBar.Tab,%20int)) (going to be deprecated).
- [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) (belongs to [Design Support Library](https://developer.android.com/training/material/design-library.html), requires [AppCompat theme](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html))

So how developers are supposed to implement tabs on Android 5.0+ (API21+, Lolipop+) applications? Using deprecated stuff is rejected. Using `TabLayout` leads to `AppCompat` usage.

Android Material usage docs:
https://developer.android.com/training/material/index.html

I haven't found any single document describing how tabs should be implemented, except for `AppCompatActivity` or [android.support.design.widget.TabLayout](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout).

I mean, this looks like nonsense:

- Android releases Material Design.
- Developers cannot use Material Design directly, because there are no components (e.g. Tabs) in API21+, and are forced to use `Theme.AppCompat` stuff instead.

Comment: I'm not certain if I'm following what you're saying, but `Theme.AppCompat` is `Theme.Material` on Lollipop and up.

Comment: Isn't `Theme.AppCompat` was created to support pre-Lolipop devices. And everything after-Lolipop should use `Theme.Material`? https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Comment: `Theme.AppCompat` covers 'em all. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39088184

Comment: Ok, so I want to move away from `AppCompatActivity` and other `app-compat` stuff,  I want to drop all pre-Lolipop devices suppport - I still need to use `Theme.AppCompat`, because there are components (e.g. `TabLayout` or `ViewPager`) that don't have analogs in 21+ devices. Is that right?

Comment: Theme AppCompat is what you need. Don't be fooled by Google's stupid decisions when it comes to naming stuff.

Comment: Correct. The same goes for Fragments and many other silliness in the world of Android. Android O is rumored to raise this to API 14 (for all support libraries), we will see.  In the mean time, yes, you have to use AppCompat. Bear in mind (if you peek inside these components) most are designed to use +21 code when they are run on such apis and basically "fall back" to Compat mode when needed.

Comment: Ok, well thanks for clarification. @MartinMarconcini please, add a few words as an answer (so I can accept it) and let other struggling souls know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppCompat was created to ease need of having to maintain different components / values for different APIs. It handles (as best as the platform/api allows) all the Material design stuff for you.

Some components, like CardView (support library v7 at the time of writing), has internal implementations for different API levels. For example on anything below API 21, it has to render the shadows differently (for "elevation" is not really supported in those APIs).

As such, and as silly as it sounds, you have to use `AppCompat` even tho you only want to latest and greatest.

One would wish Google would do *the right thing* one day, and not only stop supporting old devices (they are fine, they work, they are old, leave them in peace, offer critical security patches if needed) and move forwards in time supporting less "old apis", but also remove the "support libraries" altogether. I don't want to know which version of a Fragment I am supposed to use. I don't want to think about "FragmentManager or SupportFragmentManager", I don't even want to think about a ChildFragmentManager (wtf…?), etc.

Kudos for targeting API 21+, I would do the same if I were developing my own app. :-)