# Using design library with Theme.Material

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat

My boss  requires that I use:

```
android:Theme.Material
```

instead of:

```
Theme.AppCompat
```

Theme style:

```
<style
    name="AppTheme"
    parent="android:Theme.Material">

    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

He also requires that I use:

```
BottomNavigationView
```

Which is a part of design library and requires AppCompat. I don't see a way to use BottomNavigationView with android:Theme.Material

I am new to Android, but as far as I understand AppCompat uses 100% Material Theme for Android versions >21.

How can I argue with my boss that we should use Theme.AppCompat for a project?

Comment: The [answer on this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39088064/material-design-appcompat-and-backwards-compatibility) was written by a Google employee, so maybe direct him there? There's probably relevant blog posts out there, too, somewhere.

Comment: Yup, just use `Theme.AppCompat`. There are fixes all the way up through Android 7.0 to make it consistent that you won't get if you use `Theme.Material` directly.